# sync data between windows phone 8 using sqlce4 and Winform using sqlserver

Tags: windows-phone-8, synchronization

Hello I want to sync data between wp8(using sql compact database) and desktop application (using sql server)

Please tell the possible ways.

I developed same application on windows phone 6.5.

I used About Remote Data Access Synchronization to sync data.

Now client want to upgrade this on WP8.

What ways will be suitable (i found two )

1)using webservice 
2)sync framework (compatible with sql CE 4??)

in my previous application
i used RDA.
Mobile connected with pc via active sync
Then i push the table to sqlserver and run a sp on sql server.
After that i pull tables on windows mobile database.

How this things can be obtained easily on WP8?

Thanks